# How to get user input for the size of Array

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that can create an array with size based on user input.

How do I create an array with size based on the user input?
This is what I have so far:

```
printf("Enter the number of chars needed in the array: ");
int size;
scanf("%d", &size);
char char_array[size];
```

Comment: Did you read this Question and Answer that address this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749754/c-user-input-size-of-array.

Comment: I just tested it to make sure. Your code compiles without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations on starting to learn, are you following a tutorial of some sort? The next thing you should be learning about is [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), as opposed to static allocation (size known at compile time) on the stack.

From that Wikipedia page's examples:

> Creating an array of ten integers with automatic scope is straightforward in C:
>
> ```
> int array[10];
> ```
>
> However, the size of the array is fixed at compile time. If one wishes to allocate a similar array dynamically, the following code can be used:
>
> ```
> int *array = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
> ```

Obviously for your case, replace `int` with `char` and `10` with `size`.

And ***always*** (this is the tricky thing about dynamic allocation) remember to `free()` any memory you have `malloc`ed once you're finished with it!

Comment: From that same wiki page: "C99 offered variable-length arrays as an alternative stack allocation mechanism - however, this feature was relegated to optional in the later C11 standard." Which is 7 years old, now, and can be considered "current": "This new version mainly standardizes features that have already been supported by common contemporary compilers" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision))

Comment: @usr2564301 that's correct, so "current" compilers are _no longer_ required to support VLAs. Sounds like a good reason to avoid them!