# Dynamically allocated array cannot be used with fscanf?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to use `fscanf` to store a file of `int`s separated by space into an array. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("a.txt", "r");
    int m = 0, n = 0;
    int i, j;
    char temp[256];
    while (fgets(temp, 256, fp) != NULL)
        m++; //gets m
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(temp); i++)
        if (temp[i] == ' ')
            n++;
    n++; //gets n
    int num[m][n];
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &num[i][j]);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d", num[i][j]);
        puts(""); //prints the VLA
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the file (a.txt) looks like this:

```
0 0 0  
0 0 0
```

But what I get is like this:

```
16537088  11532152  13701243  
11531888         3  13701455
```

What could be the problem? Anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous issues here, not to do with variable length (actually dynamically allocated in your case) arrays:

1. You use `fgets` to read through the file once, meaning the file pointer is now pointing at the end of the file. When you use `fscanf`, it tries to read past the end of file instead of reading from the start as desired.
2. You forgot to `#include <string.h>` for `strlen`.
3. When printing the values, you need to add a space after `%d` in order to print the values with spaces apart.

Lastly, this method of dynamically allocating arrays is not recommended. It is better to use `malloc` and `free` as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22749783/12372506), although this will work assuming you're using C99 or later that allows this syntax.

My fixed code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("a.txt", "r");
    int m = 0, n = 0;
    int i, j;
    char temp[256];
    while (fgets(temp, 256, fp) != NULL)
        m++; //gets m
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(temp); i++)
        if (temp[i] == ' ')
            n++;
    n++; //gets n
    int num[m][n];

    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("a.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &num[i][j]);
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%d ", num[i][j]);
        puts(""); //prints the VLA
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note the closing and reopening of the file as well as the other fixes I mentioned.

Comment: It works OK if I did not `#include <string.h>`, I don't know why, but I am using Visual Studio and clang-cl (for VLAs).

Comment: @yanglifu90 I'm afraid that I can't shed much light on that—Visual Studio does have their own setup for includes and the like that I don't know anything about, sorry. It's always greatly confused me and I've never had to find out so I haven't. :)

Comment: @yanglifu90 it "worked fine" this time. Not all functions work without their declarations. And relying on implicit function definitions does not conform to C99. In any case Clang ought to display a diagnostic message. If you didn't see this then there is something very wrong with your IDE setup.

Comment: Instead of fclose/forensic, consider rewinding h file with fseek, or rewind.

Comment: Instead of doing two passes over the file, consider dynamic allocation (`malloc()` and friends) and a simple pass.

Comment: @dash-o Of course, you're right. Can't believe that slipped my mind.

Comment: @pmg Sorry, it's not coming to me. How would `malloc()` help reduce to a single pass in this case?

Comment: @CH. allocate space for, say, 10 values. Read from file into those 10 elements. Increase `realloc()` to 20 values. Read 10 more from file. Realloc to 40, read 20 more. realloc to 80, read 40 more, and so on until file is fully processed (you may shrink the array now).

Comment: @pmg Ah, okay, that makes perfect sense. Thank you. :)